# Union query won't refresh unless I close and reopen the database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a union query that won't refresh unless I close Access and re-open it.

The Union query tracks 2 sides, 1 side has numbers that have been assigned.  The other side has numbers that are  unidentified.

To keep this simple as simple as possible, the name of the query is "TOTALS_FINAL" and it produces the results I want just fine.

But it is a heavy query, so instead of making it record source on the form
Here is how I show the values on the form

```
Public Sub RefreshTOTALS()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
'Dim rsSP As DAO.Recordset

'dbOpenSnapshot is dramatically quicker than multiple Dlookups
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TOTALS_FINAL", dbOpenSnapshot)



With Form_frm_COB

.txtTOTALS_AFP = rs!AFP
.txtTOTALS_ALLT = rs!ALLT
.txtTOTALS_SP_C = rs!SP_C
.txtTOTALS_SP_O = rs!SP_O
.txtTOTALS_COMMITS = rs!COMMITS
.txtTOTALS_OBS = rs!OBS
.txtTOTALS_COM_SP_RATE = rs!COM_SP_RATE
.txtTOTALS_OBS_SP_RATE = rs!OBS_SP_RATE
.txtTOTALS_UNC = rs!UNC

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

If I may please have your permission, I have refrained from showing the details of the query because it will make this question unnecessarily complicated. Just suffice it to say that if I close the database and reopen it, this is the only way the values in this query becomes refreshed.

I have tried rs.requery, but it doesn't work either.

I can show more pieces of this query as relevant questions are asked.

Hoping there is a programatic way to refresh this when the data changes in the underlying query.

Comment: this is not a answer that will help you immediately but you should seriously consider moving the DB to a proper database like MSSQL or Oracle or MySQL. And the frontend written in a mature high level language/framework like .Net/C#. It will save you a lot of grief over the long run.(Speaking from experience)

Comment: @objectNotFound: Access as frontend is just fine, if you know what you're doing.

Comment: So this UNION query returns just one record? That's a little odd. And if you re-run the above sub, the values are not refreshed? What if you open the query directly?

Comment: Precisely. One record. it is a total summary. Yes, it boggles me because I looked directly at the query and it didn't change, so I gave up and shut down the database, only to find when I opened it back up, the value in the query had changed! I can repeat the phenomenon.

Comment: To answer the other question by -objectNotFound, I would love to use MSSQL, and C# but the client who is DOD precisely hired this contract who specializes in Access because they don't have the budget for a database admin and SQL Licensing and Visual Studio.

Comment: Then I guess the UNION query is input to an aggregation query. But anyway, this is not how Access behaves normally, so there must be something else going on. Is there some (coded) caching on startup? Or does the query (or its inputs) use VBA functions, that use static variables?

Comment: @Andre, I took what you said about caching on startup.  The word 'Static' made me look at the union query more carefully and I found that the "assigned" half uses all queries, and the unidentified half, uses a table directly (it is not from a 'make table' - but gets the values exported to it for a dual purpose)   I changed that part of the UNION into the original query and that did the trick.  Now I see the values as soon as they change and I don't need to restart.  Go figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was: the query took some of its data from a table that **caches** data from other queries, and is probably filled at startup.